# Android ListView with custom row (RadioButton and 3 TextView)

Tags: java, android, listview, radio-button

i am using a listview in a class which extends ListActivity but my row have a radio button and 3 textviews.

If i delete radiobutton from it, the metod `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` works well and i see what item have been selected but with the radiobutton i can check what item have selected.

How i can resolve this? I am using a custom adapter for build listview

Comment: Also, what is your actual question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i have a row in a listview with a radiobutton but when i click on radiobutton, dont stay checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need multi selection in the ListView that is why you're trying achieve that using RadioButton, if so, instead of RadioButton,try Checkbox, that would work great

and this tutorial will guide you how to accomplish that
http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/